# Copy particular files (whose names are saved in a list) from one folder to another

Tags: command-line

I have nearly 4 lakhs (400,000) of files in a folder named `model` and from this folder I have selected a few thousand files and their names are saved in `id.txt`. Now I want to take only the files listed in `id.txt` from the folder `model` and copy them to another folder named `selected_ids`.

The two folders are present inside the same directory `test` which contains

1. model
2. selected_ids
3. id.txt

`id.txt` contains filenames one by one
eg:

```
ENSP00000290866.4_2.pdb.xz
385719215_2.pdb.xz
GENSCAN00000006392_3.pdb.xz
```

Model folder contains nearly 3 lakh files

```
ENSP00000290866.4_2.pdb.xz
385719215_2.pdb.xz
GENSCAN00000006392_3.pdb
```

*note: in folder some files have .pdb.xz extension and some only .pdb

I know how to copy a single file from one folder to another like this

```
cp model/ENSP00000290866.4_2.pdb.xz selected_ids/
```

But I have thousands and thousands of files to copy in short time.

Can anyone give some efficient command to copy the files?

Answer (score 4):

the command you are looking is as follow,

```
cd /path/to/model
$ xargs -d '\n' -a /path/to/id.txt cp -t /path/to/selected_ids
```

this will read the files name saved in id.txt and copy to selected_ids directory.

Comment: @Nitha please stop having these long discussions in the comments. It is very hard for anyone else to follow. All these details need to be added *to your question*. We need to know what you tied and how it failed and, most importantly, we need to know what the actual file names are. So please edit your question and show us an actual example with a few ids and a few files. Including pdb and pdb.xz extensions. Finally, it sounds like you might be interested in our new site: [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 0):

Use `while IFS= read -r variable; do... done < input.txt` structure to read file line by line and execute desired code in `...` part. This is a standard `bash` way to read file line-by-line and act upon it. With the directory as you described, it should be done as so:

```
$ tree                                                                                                                                               
.
├── 385719215_2.pdb.xz
├── ENSP00000290866.4_2.pdb.xz
├── GENSCAN00000006392_3.pdb.xz
├── id.txt
├── model
└── selected_ids

2 directories, 4 files
$ while IFS= read -r file; do cp "$file" selected_ids/"$file" ;done < id.txt                                                                         
$ tree
.
├── 385719215_2.pdb.xz
├── ENSP00000290866.4_2.pdb.xz
├── GENSCAN00000006392_3.pdb.xz
├── id.txt
├── model
└── selected_ids
    ├── 385719215_2.pdb.xz
    ├── ENSP00000290866.4_2.pdb.xz
    └── GENSCAN00000006392_3.pdb.xz
```

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04: `The program 'tree' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install tree`

Comment: @madneon  Yeah, it's not a default program, but `tree` isn't important as far as  the question goes, it's used here only for giving visual idea of how directory is structured. The important part is the `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is no white-spaces in input file you can simply use `for` loop:

```
for f in $(<id.txt); do cp -v "model/$f" selected_ids/;done
```

If you having trouble with "\r" at the end of file names (most likely file was saved in Windows-family OS), you also need to trim variable `$f`:

```
for f in $(<id.txt); do f=`echo $f|tr -d "\n\r"`; cp -v "model/$f" selected_ids/; done
```

*Note that `cp` with option `-v` will display the current file being copied, so its easy to verify this batch copying process.*